# Testing input value to be an empty string on button click React Testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a React component. It is an input element that on button click the value is set to "".

My test keeps on failing but I am confused because I can see that it does in fact work on button click.

Heres the test

```js
const mockedSetSearch = jest.fn();
const mockedSearch = "Hello world";


  it("Input should be cleared on 'clear' button click", () => {
    render(
      <PostSearch setUserSearch={mockedSetSearch} userSearch={mockedSearch} />
    );
    const inputElement = screen.getByPlaceholderText(
      /Search posts/i
    ) as HTMLInputElement;
    fireEvent.change(inputElement, { target: { value: "Hello World" } });
    const buttonElement = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /clear/i });
    fireEvent.click(buttonElement);
// LINE BELOW FAILS THE TEST
    expect(inputElement.value).toBe("");
  });
```

P.S I am using TypeScript + Nextjs

Comment: I don't know the testing framework, but assuming clicking the button changes the state, is it possible your `expect(inputElement.value).toBe("")` executes before the page has rerendered and the input updated?

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap async stuff like clicks in [*act*](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#act). Because hooks and setState are async, so whatever logic you have async too. So test assertion happen before component change value.

Possibly need to use [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor)

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62473970/best-way-to-test-input-value-in-dom-testing-library-or-react-testing-library)

```
import { act } from @testing-library/react

it("Input should be cleared on 'clear' button click", () => {
    render(
      <PostSearch setUserSearch={mockedSetSearch} userSearch={mockedSearch} />
    );
    const inputElement = screen.getByPlaceholderText(
      /Search posts/i
    ) as HTMLInputElement;
    act(() => {
      fireEvent.change(inputElement, { target: { value: "Hello World" } });
    })
    const buttonElement = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /clear/i });
    act(() => {
      fireEvent.click(buttonElement);
    })
// LINE BELOW FAILS THE TEST
 //   expect(inputElement.value).toBe("");

    await waitFor(() => {
     expect(inputElement).toHaveValue("");
    });
    // or await waitFor(() => {
    //   expect(screen.getByPlaceholderText(
    //    /Search posts/i
    //  ) as HTMLInputElement).toHaveValue("");
    // });

  });
```